# JSP url argument passing

Tags: jsp, url, servlets

Is there any way to pass params to the function in this way:
      *www.smth.com/func.jsp/1/2/3*
but not like this:
      *www.smth.com/func.jsp?a=1&b=2&c3*
Using PHP i just define the method
      *function func($a, $b, $c) {*
      *...* 
      *}*
Of course I can write
      *www.smth.com/func.jsp?1&2&3*
but this is not so clean as
      *www.smth.com/func.jsp/1/2/3*

thank you

Comment: It's certainly not "just" like that in PHP. You have to configure the webserver as well to support *multiviews* and to extract the params from `PATH_INFO`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to do this. It's similar to apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).